# ZF2 - Editing only one part of data

Tags: php, zend-framework2, editing

I have a product table with many fields (id, label, reference, key_product, ...), the key_product is an encrypted value.

my exchangeArray function in the product model is normal except that when it comes to the key_product i do like so :

```
    public function exchangeArray($data){        
    $this->key_product = (isset($data['key_product'])) ? sh1($data['key_product']) : $this->key_product;
   }
```

while editing my product data, i display the key_product empty so if the user enters a value then it will be stored in database. my problem is when the user don't enter a value, i would like to keep the old value in the database, except that when i hydrate data, and come to the exchangeArray function, it always encrypt the key_product value, so i find my self with the same value encrypted twice.

My question is how to edit the product's data without editing the key_product field if no key_product was entered.
any suggestions will be most welcome.
Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

Hi I think that you can do this from productTable .

```
public function updateProduct(Product $product)
{
    $data = array (
        'id' => $product->id,
        'label' => $product->label,
        'reference' => $product->reference,
        //... other 
    );

    if($product->key_product != null) {
        $data['key_product'] = $product->key_product;
    }
    //else key_product w'll not be changed

    $id = (int) $product->id;
    $this->tableGateway->update($data, array('id' => $id));
}
```

and your  exchangeArray w'll become like this :

```
public function exchangeArray($data) 
{        
    $this->key_product = (isset($data['key_product'])) ? sh1($data['key_product']) : null;
}
```